# Matplotlib: draw a series of radial lines on PolarAxes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to replicate a certain plot using matplotlib: it should look something like this.

[image: Final plot]

I have seen that it it possible to use the PolarAxes to draw radial points: for istance i've made a really simple polar plot with the following snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
# Set the axes as polar
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
# Draw some points
ax.plot([0],[1], 'o')
ax.plot([3],[1], 'o')
ax.plot([6],[1], 'o')

# Go clockwise
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Start from the top
ax.set_theta_offset(1.570796327)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

And i get something like this:

[image: First example]

So my question is: is there a way to draw the lines as in the first figure, and to adjust the width in order to fit in the whole circonference? Also some hints on how to handle the colors would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** the data that has to be plotted is quite simple: each track is an array of floats whose range is between 0 and 9 (and the color is derived from the colormap RdYlGn). The array length are multiple of 96.

**UPDATE 2:** that's the snipped that i have used

```
# mydata is a simple list of floats
a = np.array([[x for i in range(10)] for x in mydata])

# construct the grid
radius = np.linspace(0.2,0.4,10)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,len(a))
R,T  = np.meshgrid(radius,theta)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar = True)

# plot the values using the appropriate colormap
ax.pcolor(T,R,a,cmap=cm.RdYlGn)
```

Comment: Can you give an idea of what format your data is in?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry i forgot about that: updating in a second...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without more information about how your data is organized it is difficult to say what the best way to recreate this plot would be. It is easy to draw lines of different widths and colors on a polar plot. Though if you need as many as in your example, things may get slow. I have also provided an example of a polar pseudo-color plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create radius and theta arrays, and a 2d radius/theta array
radius = np.linspace(0.2,0.4,51)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,51)
R,T  = np.meshgrid(radius,theta)

#Calculate some values to plot
Zfun = lambda R,T: R**2*np.cos(T)
Z = Zfun(R,T)

#Create figure and polar axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar = True)

ax.pcolor(T,R,Z)    #Plot calculated values

#Plot thick red section and label it
theta = np.linspace(0,np.pi/4,21)
ax.plot(theta,[1.23 for t in theta],color='#AA5555',linewidth=10)   #Colors are set by hex codes
ax.text(np.pi/8,1.25,"Text")

ax.set_rmax(1.25)   #Set maximum radius

#Turn off polar labels
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer: i've updated the question with the data format. I've noticed that you have used the pcolor function for the inner track and it seems good, however each rectangle has a gradient, and i would like a single color for each rectangle. Do you think that i can use the normal plot function that you have used for the outer track?

Comment: I am confused... why do you made a R, T grid, and a function from (R,T) and then when you plot you swap the order or R and T?

Comment: If the function you're working with is a function of radius and angle, it is just as valid to say that it is a function of angle and radius. The order doesn't matter. You use these arrays to calculate values in a third dimension so you only need to be self consistent. It is conventional when working in polar coordinates to write the radius as the first variable. For me this is second nature. That said, the first argument is the angle array and the second argument is the radius array when using polar axes in matplotlib. We just need to pass the arguments in the right order to plot it correctly.